# storePubliclyAs not saving in public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I don't know if I have misunderstood something, but I call the following method during a file upload:

```
$cover->storePubliclyAs($coverAsset->dir, $coverAsset->preview_name);
```

`$coverAsset->dir` returns `businesses/2` and `$coverAsset->preview_name` returns a hashed file name.

After doing the upload I end up with a file at:
`storage/app/businesses/1/pre-AxDMVlSN.jpeg`

I am confused, why isn't the file saved in `storage/app/public/businesses/...`? I would expect the 'publicly' part to put it in the public folder of the storage directory structure provided by Laravel.

I looked at my filesystems configuration:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...
```

It feels like the `local` disk is used instead of the `public` disk? How do I find out which one is used by `UploadedFile->storePubliclyAs` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `storePubliclyAs` based from this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L61

It just sets the *file*'s visibility into **public**, contrary to what you assumed that it will move/store the *file* into the **public folder**.

To actually select a *disk* where you want it to be stored. Just use the third optional parameter of the `storePubliclyAs` which is the `$options` parameter.

**Note that, if you didn't choose a disk (by passing an $options parameter), Laravel will use the default selected disk based from your filesystems.php config file.**

According to what I've read about the code, you can just pass the **disk name** as the third parameter.

So instead of this:

`$cover->storePubliclyAs($coverAsset->dir, $coverAsset->preview_name);`

Use this (we'll use `public` since you want to store it in the disk named *public*):

`$cover->storePubliclyAs($coverAsset->dir, $coverAsset->preview_name, 'public');`

---

Furthermore, take a look at Laravel's default **filesystems.php**: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php#L16

That line looks for a `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` entry in the *.env* file, however if it didn't find one, it will use the second parameter; by default which is `local`.

I think you're config is defaulting into the `local` disk. What you may try to do is either to append `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public` in your *.env* file or change the second parameter in the **filesystems.php** to `public`.

Please let me know if there are any errors, since I haven't tried anything of this, I've just read the code.

If want to trace the code yourself, you can look it up here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php